# How to print a Django date / time field?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print a Django date / time field in the shell via the "str" function, but I get an error:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, editable=False)
    dt_tm = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'owner: ' + str(self.owner) + ', date / time: ' + 
            str(self.dt_tm)

>>> foo = Foo(user=mr_bar, dt_tm=now())
>>> foo
...
TypeError: Can't convert 'datetime.datetime' object to str implicitly
```

I am not fussy about the date / time format as I won't be using this elsewhere in my application, just in the shell.

Comment: Using `str()` as you are doing should work. Try restarting the shell, in case you are using an old version of your code.

Comment: A best practice to convert datetime object into string is to user strftime.

Comment: @Alasdair yeah that was the problem, thanks.

Comment: @rkatkam like I said I'm not bothered about the format, but thanks anyway.